# VB.net WebBrowser change version of IE

Tags: vb.net, registry, webbrowser-control, version, emulation

I want to change the version of my browser control to IE 11 (which I have on my computer)
I tried this:

```
Dim registrybrowser As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", True)
registrybrowser.SetValue("myapp.vshost.exe", 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
registrybrowser.SetValue("myapp.exe", 11000, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

but it gave me this error:

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
   at myapp.My.MyApplication.MyApplication_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in Visual Studio\Projects\myapp\ApplicationEvents.vb:line 16
The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer
```

I have tried other ways, but they have failed too. I have not worked much with registry, so I really dont know why this is occurring.

Also, if I were to try and run it on a computer without IE 11, would it still work, or would I have to set the value entered in the registry to adjust to whichever version of IE is installed.

Thank you

Comment: Use `Registry.CurrentUser` instead of `Registry.LocalMachine`.

Comment: @Noseratio i tried that too - and got a 'NullReferenceException' on the line that I open the subkey

Comment: Because if a registry key doesn't exist, you need to create it first.

Comment: thank you. I tried just removing the line with the myapp.vshost.exe and it worked fine. that had been the problem